# What is causing Allowed memory size of bytes exhausted

Tags: php, apache-2.4

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /home/usermedi/public_html/wp-includes/meta.php on line 574


log_errors  On  On
log_errors_max_len  1024    1024
mail.add_x_header   Off Off
mail.force_extra_parameters no value    no value
mail.log    no value    no value
max_execution_time  3000    3000
max_file_uploads    20  20
max_input_nesting_level 64  64
max_input_time  6000    6000
max_input_vars  1000    1000
memory_limit    4096M   4096M
open_basedir    no value    no value
output_buffering    no value    no value
output_handler  no value    no value
post_max_size   8M  8M
```

What is causing this to happen?

This is Apache 2.4 with PHP 5.4 on a default CPanel setup.

Comment: Did you look at your plugins yet?

Comment: Yea, this was happening when trying to remove some of them. The rest have already been removed. Maybe they will need to be removed manually? I just can't see them maxing out 4GBs? The server has 32GBs of RAM and this is the only site on the server.

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of PHP, perhaps a CGI or something else?   It sure looks like you still have a copy of PHP with a  a 256M memory_limit.

Comment: I shouldn't. I even did a server reboot. Everything id FastCGI and controlled by Apache.

Comment: Can you install http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-php-info/ or add a PHP file to your docroot to show the `phpinfo()`? This would show you the location of the INI file being used for this site?

Comment: Yes, that is shown above. I've confirmed what php.ini file is being used and that is shows 4096MB of RAM allowed :)

Comment: are you using Suhosin with php? it has it's own memory_limit setting that overrides the php setting

Comment: since you're using wordpress also check for
 define('WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the comments above you're using WordPress and in that case you're probably being bitten by `WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT` which is set to 256MB by default.

That's probably not your problem though. Raising that limit may help in the short term but 256MB is already *way* bigger than a single WordPress request should consume. If you're not doing anything particularly out of the ordinary then you need to find out what's consuming so much RAM.